# Testing Play Integrity API in Android SDK emulator

Tags: google-play-store, security, android-emulator, google-play-services, android-sdk

I want to test my app with the Google Play verdict API, especially `MEETS_STRONG_INTEGRITY`. To test, I plan to use Android Studio as I have always done, but when I create a device, I cannot approve the validations of said app.

Does anyone know how to "activate and deactivate" these APIs in the Android Studio emulator, so that it allows me to do my relevant tests?

For now, everything appears red, implying that it is a vulnerable and unsafe device.

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge "strong_integrity" requires hardware based security, thus an emulator will by definition never meet strong_integrity. You need to use physical devices for testing.

Comment: that's right.

And it would be unfortunate if android studio does not have the ability to emulate that, being the official android emulator.

I have only one device, which is my personal one, and since it is rooted, it does not pass strong integrity. :(

Comment: You have to look at the topic from the opposite direction: If Android Studio Emulator would be able to pass strong_integrity then the whole Play Integrity API would be worthless: The emulator is open source so there would be a way to bypass strong_integrity without actual security hardware in a software that everybody can run/modify/compile. If you can run your app in emulator every user can do the same so what would you gain by checking strong_integrity?